# does using a custom block allocator to allocate pointers put in array solve cash missing problems?

Tags: arrays, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocator

Let's say we have a class `A` , and we have an array of pointers to `A` objects, when I loop through each element in that array I may cause cash miss because each object is in a different place in memory and they are not aligned in the same block one after another, because it is an array of pointers to objects and not of the actual objects .

I want to solve this problem by creating a custom allocator, that I use to allocate these objects and put their pointers in the array. The allocator ensures  that all objects are always next to one another in memory, aligned in a block. Does that solve cash missing problems when iterating the array ?

More details:

i will create a custom allocator , this allocator will alloc a block of memory big enough to handle all objects , later when i alloc an object , this allocator will choose the free space within that block trying each time to make all objects placed one next to another , that way they are loaded at once to cash memory and will cause less cash miss

Comment: What? I mean about your suggested solution.

Comment: i will create a custom allocator , this allocator will alloc a block of memory big enough to handle all objects , later when i alloc an object , this allocator will choose the free space within that block trying each time to make all objects placed one next to another , that way they are loaded at once to cash memory and will cause less cash miss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access the first object via the first pointer, it is true that initially several pointers will be fetched into cache, and then several objects.

So when you access the second pointer it will be already be in cache indeed, so will the second object. And so on.

So yes, this will help, but can't you just use the block of memory that holds the actual objects directly, instead of pointers? If not, try to re-evaluate your design. Using the objects directly will maximize the data locality of your objects.

Comment: Nice ! i really have use pointers , because the objects have virtual functions that are allowed to be overridden ,besides the objects will be of diffrent size ( same base class )... ( the allocator can handle this )

Comment: i was waiting for another one , still , dont worry buddy i never forget , i will accept the best answer ;) , please try to improve it by adding references to the origines of the information , and remove the 'probably' make things certain because i know thats probable